# Why is my reactjs project loading endlessly?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

In my project i use "tailwindcss". I don't have any error but my project don't load. Just website loading and it's all. I give my github repo instead code, beacause i don't know, where problem. I hope, i can write links

Project - https://github.com/kirilchistov/react-movies

Problem:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a loop in you header file. for the default path `<popular/>` is called which calls `<header/>` which again calls `<popular/>`. you should do all the route management in the `app.jsx` file.